# 'geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape a dynamic website using the following code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

# specify the url
urlpage = 'https://www.paddypower.com/mixed-martial-arts' 
print(urlpage)
# run firefox webdriver from executable path of your choice
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\Windows\System32\drivers\DriverData\geckodriver.exe')
# get web page
driver.get(urlpage)
# execute script to scroll down the page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
# sleep for 30s
time.sleep(30)
# driver.quit()
```

And, I get the following error: " os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)

WebDriverException: 'geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH."

geckodriver.exe is definitely in the system variables path, and the executable path is definitely correct. I am not sure how to correct this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you have `geckodriver.exe` in folder `'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\DriverData` then in `PATH` you need only folder name `'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\DriverData` without file name `geckodriver.exe`. And then you don't need `executable_path=`. But if you use `executable_path=` then better use raw string `r"C:\..."` because char \ has special meaning (like `\n`, `\t`) in all strings - even in path.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I get the same error message when I don't use executable path. I get the same message when I implement everything you've suggested. Could it be a problem with geckodriver itself?